# Arraylist and recursive implementation

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, arraylist

I am trying to outline a java recursive implementation for a function which returns true if all the elements in the list are single digit(i.e.<10). Can assume the list only contains positive numbers.

Here is what I have tried, but it keeps returning true even there is a 2 digits number in the list.

import java.util.*;

public class Q3b {

```
static boolean allSingleDigit(ArrayList list) {
    if (list.size() == 0)
        return false;
    else {
        int first = (Integer) list.get(0);
        list.remove(0);

        if (first < 10)
            return true;
        else
            return allSingleDigit(list);
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList();
    Collections.addAll(list, 4, 25, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3);
    boolean res1 = allSingleDigit(new ArrayList(list));
    System.out.println("List Contains all single number" + res1);
}
```

}

any suggestions guys ?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you might want to flip the logic slightly so that it returns true only when there are no elements left in the array;

```
static boolean allSingleDigit(ArrayList list) {
if (list.size() == 0)
    return true;
else {
    int first = (Integer) list.get(0);
    list.remove(0);

    if (first < 10)
        return allSingleDigit(list);
    else
        return false
}
```

Comment: oh no wiat, it is working now. i forget to return true at the start.

Answer (score 2):

Your program seems fine, only problem is you should return `false` as soon as first element `>= 10` is encountered and return `true` when list size is `0`. Modify it as shown below:

```
static boolean allSingleDigit(List<Integer> list) {
  if (list.size() == 0)
    return true;

  int first = list.remove(0);

  if (first == null || first >= 10)
    return false;
  else
    return allSingleDigit(list);

}
```

You could optimize it and make it more concise by using generic `List` and using `remove()` method from `List` directly. I have also added missing `null` check.

Comment: i changed it to

 if (first >= 10)
       return false;
   else
    return allSingleDigit(list);
  }

now I get false all the time...

Comment: Sorry, I missed first `if` clause. Updated it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the method you wanted.

```
static boolean allSingleDigit(ArrayList list) {
    if (list.size() == 0)
        return true;
    else {
        int first = (Integer) list.get(0);
        list.remove(0);

        if (first >= 10)
            return false;
        else
            return allSingleDigit(list);
    }

}
```

I have just changed in your code.